# Помогите справиться с засильем "то" во всех падежах

Tags: пунктуация

> Каково же было наше изумление, когда коридор битком набили
>   литературные критики и наперебой заговорили о том, что намеревались
>   разорвать нас на кусочки – за то, что мы, для начала, наплевали на
>   волю автора и за то, что прозу Сэлинджера, в любом случае, просто
>   невозможно поставить в театре, но после спектакля они растеряли свой
>   пыл?!

Верна ли пунктуация?

Может, не в "том" дело (смущающее мой слух); может, поставленное мной тире (или иные знаки) сбивает вопросительную интонацию предложения?

**;** после "волю автора"?

А "для начала" и "в любом случае" - ничего в запятых смотрятся?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каково же было наше изумление, когда коридор битком набили литературные критики и наперебой заговорили о том, что  **они** намеревались разорвать нас на кусочки, ― **за то, что мы, для начала, наплевали на волю автора; за то, что прозу Сэлинджера, в любом случае,  просто невозможно поставить в театре**, ― но после спектакля  растеряли свой пыл.

Пояснение

1) **Вставка обособляется двумя тире,** это как бы отдельный текст со своей интонацией. Слова "для начала, в любом случае" ― аналоги "во-первых, во-вторых.

2) **Точку с запятой можно поставить,** она будет соответствовать небольшой паузе в эмоциональной речи критиков (если нет, то перед И нужна запятая).

3) Местоимение "они" перенесено. При чтении текста  **вначале кажется**, что должно быть "намереваются", а не "намеревались", то есть не сразу понятна их реакция.